# Best way to do headshot decapitation?

Tags: blender, unreal

I'm using UE4 and blender. I was wondering what the process is of preparing in the 3D software and then making a head burst animation upon headshot. I don't want to do destructible meshes because they are sharp jagged fragments... I want it to literally burst and splash blood. How can I do this? Any support is appreciated.

Comment: I have no experience with UE4, but I would do the head as a separate submesh and in the event of a headshot remove that mesh and replace it with a particle effect which splatters blood and skull fragments everywhere. In that particle effect I would not consider the original head mesh at all. I would just spawn random gore-particles in a head-sized sphere. The head-bursting will be so quick that nobody would notice that shortcut (Unless you want to show it in super slow-motion).

Comment: @Philipp in which case I would still swap the original mesh with a new one that has the detailed slow-mo animation. ;)

Comment: Hey Philipp, yea I thought about that but how could I line up the head to the body so that it looks connected?

Comment: Parent it to the body the same as you would parent a gun to the hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 2 blueprints, 1 for head and 1 for body. Then in construction script of the main blueprint, spawn both and add head to body. When the head drops, unattach it from the body and add a force in the desired direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think for the blood splashing you could use a particles system and make it play when a headshot it done. For the head burst I would divide the mesh in blender into pieces and then just move them away from the centre.